# How do I select rows based on multiple conditions in a subquery in KQL (Kusto)?

Tags: kql

As an example, if I have:

#### NotifChain

| EventId | NotiId | AckedBy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 345 | 999 | 3736 |
| 777 | 999 |  |
| 298 | 777 | 3337 |
| 298 | 321 |  |

#### NotifStages

| NotiId | Targets |
| --- | --- |
| 999 | [team: spuds]: [ [Group: dog]: [ [pid: 8437] [pid: 3736] ] ] |
| 777 | [team: spuds]: [ [Group: dog]: [ [pid: 3337] ] ] |
| 777 | [team: spuds]: [ [Group: cat]: [ [pid: 3736] ] ] |

#### People

| pid | name |
| --- | --- |
| 8437 | Spudz |
| 3736 | Chuckles |
| 3337 | Ralph |

For any given even, I want to list out the people who were notified, but didn't respond in KQL. I'm completely stuck. I can extract a list of pid's contacted, but have no way to iterate over them. And even if I did, there's no way I know of to say "for each pid, discared this row if there's any row in notifchain that was aked for this pid AND this event"

I want a list of EventIds AND names where they were sent a notification, but didn't ack it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this fully matches your verbal description (that would have been much easier to understand if you would have provided the expected output in the form of a table), but it can get you started:

```
let NotifChain = datatable(EventId: long, NotiId: long, AckedBy: long)
[
    345, 999, 3736,
    777, 999, long(null),
    298, 777, 3337,
    298, 321, long(null),
]
;
let NotifStages = datatable(NotiId: long, Targets: string)
[
    999, '[team: spuds]: [ [Group: dog]: [ [pid: 8437] [pid: 3736] ] ]',
    777, '[team: spuds]: [ [Group: dog]: [ [pid: 3337] ] ]',
    777, '[team: spuds]: [ [Group: cat]: [ [pid: 3736] ] ]',
]
;
let People = datatable(pid: long, name: string)
[
    8437, 'Spudz',
    3736, 'Chuckles',
    3337, 'Ralph',
]
;
NotifChain
| join kind=inner (
    NotifStages
    | extend pid = extract_all(@"pid: (\d+)", Targets)
) on NotiId
| mv-expand pid
| extend pid = tolong(pid)
| lookup People on pid
```

| EventId | NotiId | AckedBy | NotiId1 | Targets | pid | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 777 | 999 |  | 999 | [team: spuds]: [ [Group: dog]: [ [pid: 8437] [pid: 3736] ] ] | 8437 | Spudz |
| 777 | 999 |  | 999 | [team: spuds]: [ [Group: dog]: [ [pid: 8437] [pid: 3736] ] ] | 3736 | Chuckles |
| 345 | 999 | 3736 | 999 | [team: spuds]: [ [Group: dog]: [ [pid: 8437] [pid: 3736] ] ] | 8437 | Spudz |
| 345 | 999 | 3736 | 999 | [team: spuds]: [ [Group: dog]: [ [pid: 8437] [pid: 3736] ] ] | 3736 | Chuckles |
| 298 | 777 | 3337 | 777 | [team: spuds]: [ [Group: dog]: [ [pid: 3337] ] ] | 3337 | Ralph |
| 298 | 777 | 3337 | 777 | [team: spuds]: [ [Group: cat]: [ [pid: 3736] ] ] | 3736 | Chuckles |

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Basically, after extracting a list of users that were notified for a particular event, I need to somehow exclude any users that responded from my result set.

Comment: But given how badly I explained this, I think I should close and try again. Thank you for your help!